# p:dataTable and optimistic locking in JPA

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2, optimistic-locking

Given [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JkDW.png) an exemplary `<p:dataTable>` using the PrimeFaces lazy data model. The row version field as marked by `@javax.persistence.Version` in the associated JPA entity is temporarily displayed in one of the columns in read-only mode.

<sub>Needless to mention that every action is Ajaxical.</sub>

[image]

Editing this `<p:dataTable>` using a `<p:rowEditor/>` as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0fEz.png) (the first row in the table. **The row version is 1**).

[image]

When a row being edited is updated by clicking the tick mark in the Edit column as above, the row version is incremented in the database to 2 on successful update but the row version held by the data table is still 1 (see the picture below). After update is completed, the status of the data table can be viewed as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUpSx.png).

[image]

What happens now is if the same row is attempted again (without refreshing the page by sending a synchronous GET request), then it will not match the row version in the database which is currently 2 because the data table still supplies the old previous value of the version which is 1. This will cause the `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` to be thrown as if concurrent updates are detected which is evidently untrue.

Something may need to be changed drastically in the normal Ajaxical update facility provided by a `<p:dataTable>` (using a `<p:rowEditor/>`) in order for it to work correctly and synchronously with the optimistic locking strategy in JPA.

What would be the correct way to get around the situation? Dropping the `<p:rowEditor/>` in its entirely will need tremendous changes to existing applications, by the way which is quite undesired.

Comment: In other words, the entity in lazy data model is not updated after service call? The changes are not reflected in that entity?

Comment: Yes, the model backed by a `<p:dataTable>` is not updated, if something has been changed behind the back causing old/stale values to be supplied in subsequent attempts to update the same data table row unless the table itself is somehow reloaded by refreshing the current page, for example.

Comment: I'd say the updating of the model is something **you** should do. The PFdatatable can and should not know what is changed there. It could e.g. be that many other records are updated as wel. One reason this might happen is that the entity in the datamodel has become detached and before updating it, you merge it. You have to replace the detached entity in the datamodel with the merged one, not something PF can or should do. <...>

Comment: <part2>  If you want to display the updated version to, you have to either update the full datatable, or try to see if the [OmniFaces Ajax](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax) util can help out by updating just the specific row this entity is in

Comment: Table doesn't necessarily need to be updated, but the model itself must be updated. I'm only wondering why changes aren't reflected back in the entity. One probable cause would be that you're updating a copy of the entity, or that the model is holding a copy of the entity, but then you would never get an OLE in first place.

Comment: @BalusC: You would if the entity in the model is not the merged/updated one with the new version field (only the fields that were changed from the ui). If you keep using that in your model and want that to be put in the DB again it needs to be merged again and you have a different version as the one in the database. You'll get an OLE then. So if the commit has taken place, either update the version field in the entity in the datamodel with the version field from the committed one (or increment by one) or fully replace the entity. This is at least what I do.

Comment: @Kukeltje : `<p:ajax event="rowEdit" update=":form:dataTable"/>` is already there which does nothing like updating the table. If updating the entire data table were to happen somehow, then its user-friendliness would lose. For, example, if a row were edited on the 5th page (in a page-wise manned) and if the entire data table were updated after the update operation had completed, it would not stay on 5th page where it should. Instead, the data table would be reloaded and reverted to the first page which is quite undesired.

Comment: The `rowEdit` event basically ignores `update` and defaults to "current row".

Comment: (OffTopic @Tiny regarding the updating, depends on how you use the `first` attribute of the datatable and where you store/keep/reset its value) OnTopic: I could not tell since that code was not visible in the question

Comment: @Kukeltje : I assumed an MCVE completely unnecessary in this case because this could happen with any simplest possible example using a `<p:dataTable>` and I have been seeing this behaviour, since I started with PrimeFaces. Every PrimeFaces version that I used imposes this behaviour and therefore, I assumed it is quite usual.

Comment: I did not expect one, just said it was not visible. But I do think the 'error' is in your code, by not merging the updated entity into the model

Comment: @Kukeltje : I have not yet seen any example that uses explicit merging after a row is updated like [the showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml).

Comment: @Tiny, but these showcase examples do not have any JPA at all with versioning related fields which can result in OLE's. There are many real-world situations that are not covered by the showcases, simply because it is not a PF related issue or something PF can do something about in a generic way. I personally created a generic JPALazyDataModel and related controller that take an entity as a 'generics' parameter and which take care of all kinds of basic jpa related things (filtering in the db based on JPA queries, merging of changes in the model etc)

Comment: @Kukeltje : I attempted an MCVE but I avoided it as it contained much code. This only worked, when an entity with a stale version value was replaced by a newly updated entity using `List<Entity> list = (List<Entity>) getWrappedData();`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82950/discussion-between-kukeltje-and-tiny).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While editing/updating rows in a `<p:dataTable>` using a `<p:rowEditor>`, it is required to synchronize changes manually to the data model (`LazyDataModel<T>`) backed by the `<p:dataTable>` after the update operation finishes successfully.

One way to do so is to use the [`getWrappedData()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.2/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html#getWrappedData()) method available in `LazyDataModel<T>` which returns the data currently held by the data model backed by the data table in the form of `java.lang.Object`. This is a basic usage.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean extends LazyDataModel<Entity> implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Service service;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Bean() {}

    @Override
    public List<Fruit> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        setRowCount(service.getRowCount());
        // Do something, if necessary.
        // Turn the List<SortMeta> into another type like a LinkedHashMap<String, String>.
        return service.getList(first, pageSize, multiSortMeta, filters);
    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        if (event.getObject() instanceof Entity) {

            Entity entity = (Entity) event.getObject();
            Entity newEntity = service.update(entity); // A new entity from the database.

            if (newEntity != null) {

                List<Entity> entities = (List<Entity>) getWrappedData();
                int index = entities.indexOf(entity);

                if (index >= 0) { // The test may be omitted.
                    entities.set(index, newEntity);
                    // Just replace the stale/old entity by a newly updated entity in the database.
                }

                // Add an appropriate FacesMessage to indicate a success.
            } else {
                // Add an appropriate FacesMessage to indicate a failure.
            }
        } else {
            // Add an appropriate FacesMessage to indicate a failure.
        }
    }
}
```

The `onRowEdit()` method is bound to an Ajax listener inside a `<p:dataTable>`.

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{bean.onRowEdit}"/>
```

<sub>I am not going to accept this answer as there could be a better way to do so which I am unaware of. More comprehensive answers are welcomed, if any.</sub>

Comment: You can accept it in a few days I think. There will most likely not be a more convenient way that is easily understandable. A more generic solution could be created with entity listeners with a callback mechanism and hide all this boiler plate code. It could even work in a generic way if entities are updated somewhere else. But that is o/t I think

Comment: Small suggestion: maybe rewrite the example a little so the `service.update(…)` is inlined so people see the merge thing going on. But thanks for the answer

Comment: If the entity in question has no association, then the `service.update(entity)` EJB method contains only one line, `return entityManager.merge(entity);` (using CMT). If an entity however, contains associations and a cascade merge (`CascadeType.MERGE`) is set on the owning side of a relationship, EclipseLink possesses its own [behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30976896/1391249) that has to be handled adequately anyway.