# Optimistic locking while deleting entities in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, optimistic-locking

A transactional method in an EJB using CMT that removes an an entity supplied :

```
public boolean delete(Entity entity) {
    Entity managedEntity = entityManager.find(Entity.class, entity.getId());

    if (managedEntity == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }

    entityManager.remove(managedEntity);
    return !entityManager.contains(managedEntity);
}
```

The entity supplied by the client associated is a detached entity. The `entityManager.remove()` operation produces a `DELETE` DML statement like the following,

```sql
DELETE FROM db.entity WHERE ((id = ?) AND (version = ?))
```

The additional check `AND (version = ?)` should cause the `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` to be thrown, if the row version in the database conflicts with the row version in the entity.

This nevertheless would not throw the `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` even though the supplied entity were to be modified concurrently in another session by another user, since it was last read by the client (web or otherwise) because the `find()` method obtains the entity with the updated row version in another transaction (the old/stale row version (as marked by `@javax.persistence.Version`) is only contained by the detached entity supplied as a method argument).

Unlike `EntityManager#merge(T entity)`, `EntityManager#remove(Object entity)` does not accept a detached entity. It is an error passing a detached entity to `remove()`.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity must be managed to call remove: com.example.Entity[ id=1 ], try merging the detached and try the remove again.
```

Merging an entity directly before removing like,

```
entityManager.remove(entityManager.contains(entity) ? entity : entityManager.merge(entity));
```

Causes other issues, if the entity has associations.

It leaves only one alternative for optimistic locking which is to check the row version manually and then make the `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` to be thrown manually which is not the approach one may expect.

Long story short : How to make the `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` to be thrown while deleting entity(ies), if the entity to be deleted is modified behind the back by another session? The approach as mentioned above will not work for optimistic locking.

Comment: what issue do you have with merge?  If referenced entities are merged that you do not want merged, you should look at removing the cascade settings involved so that only the Entity to be deleted is merged.  Otherwise, create your own query that uses the ID and version instead of using Find.

Comment: The merge operation leaves issues as mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30976896/1391249) question in EclipseLink. This requires removing cascading but it is not always possible. it is necessary in many other cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the classing `merge`, you can do a 'soft merge' instead - just take the version from the detached instance and set it to the managed one:

```
Entity managedEntity = entityManager.find(Entity.class, entity.getId());
if (managedEntity == null) {
    throw new EntityNotFoundException();
}
managedEntity.setVersion(entity.getVersion());
```

Of course, to not to repeat yourself, depending on the hierarchy of your DAOs, Repositories etc, you can make a generic `softMerge` method which will load the managed entity, take the version from the detached instance and set it to the managed one.

Comment: The setter method of the `@javax.persistence.Version` field is declared `protected` as it should be in order to prevent potential inadvertent changes to the version field.

Comment: True, but you want to change it now explicitly. :) As an alternative, generic `softMerge` method could use reflection to set it so that it works for all the entities. Since `softMerge` would be part of the framework, it's fine to use reflection.